# Iterate through object array and filter it based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have object array which contains a lot of duplicate/useless data.  I need to filter based on customer id and pick the object with the latest date.  The data looks something like this:

```
let data = [
  {
    CUSTOMER_PERMANENT_ID: "2495",
    EMAIL: "abs@gmail.com",
    EVENT_ACTIVATION_TIME: "2019-10-25 13:57:38.79",
  },
  {
    CUSTOMER_PERMANENT_ID: "2495",
    EMAIL: "abs@gmail.com",
    EVENT_ACTIVATION_TIME: "2019-10-28 20:04:49.016",
  },
  {
    CUSTOMER_PERMANENT_ID: "2495",
    EMAIL: "abs@gmail.com",
    EVENT_ACTIVATION_TIME: "2019-10-28 20:04:49.019",
  },
  {
    CUSTOMER_PERMANENT_ID: "5995",
    EMAIL: "John@gmail.com",
    EVENT_ACTIVATION_TIME: "2019-10-28 17:24:10.98",
  }
]
```

I have tried the following function, but it only works if there are two duplicate objects, if there are more than two it return all the objects.

```
public fixDcppSelectedClientData() {
    let result = [];

    for (let item of this.arr) {
      for (let checkingItem of this.arr) {
        if (
          this.arr.indexOf(item) !=
            this.arr.indexOf(checkingItem) &&
          item.CUSTOMER_PERMANENT_ID == checkingItem.CUSTOMER_PERMANENT_ID &&
          new Date(item.EVENT_ACTIVATION_TIME).getTime() <
            new Date(checkingItem.EVENT_ACTIVATION_TIME).getTime()
        ) {
          if (result.indexOf(checkingItem) == -1) {
            result.push(checkingItem);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    console.log("filtered data is ", result);
  }
```

I need to study this topic way more, however if anyone can help in the meantime it would be great.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let id = "2495"
const query = data
    .filter( obj => obj.CUSTOMER_PERMANENT_ID === id )
    .sort( (obj1, obj2) => 
        (obj1.EVENT_ACTIVATION_TIME < obj2.EVENT_ACTIVATION_TIME) ? 1 : -1 
    )

console.log('latest', query[0]);
console.log('second to latest', query[1]);
console.log('all with this id', query)
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy, how would you find the next instance of 2495 without hard coding it?  Thing is this object I have to filter is massive

Comment: see above edits. Javascript can filter quite large arrays of data, as long as you could get it to instance. I've done it with object worse up to 10 mb, thousands of entries

Comment: very interesting I will check this out

Comment: the sort is inefficient.  that could easily have been changed from O(N log N) to O(N) by only using a min value in a reduce

Answer (score 0):

this code filter duplicates id

```js
var newArr = data.filter((x, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (
    t.CUSTOMER_PERMANENT_ID === x.CUSTOMER_PERMANENT_ID)));

console.log(newArr);
```